# How to prevent replay attacks with JWE?

Tags: jwt, json, replay-detection, jws

I am used to using JWTs so when I needed the same behavior but with no plaintext user data I looked at JWE. JWE is very similar to JWT; however, I did not see the `exp`, `nbf` or `iat` fields which limit the time the message is valid for (preventing replays after the `exp` time).

My question is: in practice how do you protect JWE from being used for replay attacks?

- Is the JWE header signed? Can I just put those time-restrictive fields in it?
- Seems a little sketchy, but could I potentially use the `iv` as the `nbf` and have an implicit `exp` time of say 1 minute after that? or maybe squeeze the `nbf` and `exp` both as the IV?
- If I have to nest the JWE in a JWT to prevent replay, is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can nest a *JWT inside a JWE* (not the other way around, as you mention in your last point), where the JWT can have the fields you want.

See a short explanation [here](https://www.scottbrady91.com/jose/json-web-encryption).